# Unwanted style decoration in an answer

Tags: discussion, editing

I have answered a question correctly and another user made some edits that includes only formatting (making the text bold). Should this be allowed in this community? Also, I think this is a continuity of [this](https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2601/how-do-we-prevent-discourage-or-punish-users-for-making-pointless-edits-to-que) post. Here is the image.

[image: Unnecessary edit]

## !!!Update!!!

@time - 10:02:14 20 February 2020 Thursday

Here is yet another edit made by the same person. Are the modulators seeing this or not.

[image: Unnecessary edit number 2]

Comment: I know this post didn't exist at the time of writing, but does this answer your question? [How to flag pointless edits](https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2646/how-to-flag-pointless-edits). The correct answer is flag it.