# How to flag pointless edits

Tags: support, editing, reputation, users

Is it possible to flag or report useless edits made by users who obviously take advantage of +2pts per edit? I saw this user 'exhibit' this behavior and checked the edits. They don't provide any useful information to the questions that were asked. I watched the user for a few hours over several question edits but he still continues doing it :)

Is there a way to stop him?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4):

flag the post with `i need of moderator intervention`

write your detail summary then @amitbera and @marius can take proper action for that user

Comment: but wouldn't that affect the original author of the post?

Comment: @daina it will not affect as its manual process and moderator has to do action manually so its just way to contact them

Comment: understood! thank you!