# Users are still making minor/pointless edits to questions in order to gain reputation

Tags: discussion, editing

A few years ago I noticed users making lots of minor edits to questions in order to gain reputation  points on the Magento / Stack Exchange network. At the time, I posted a question about this: [How do we prevent, discourage, or punish users for making pointless edits to questions?](https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2601/how-do-we-prevent-discourage-or-punish-users-for-making-pointless-edits-to-que)

Since then, not much has improved. I have still noticed users doing this "point farming" by making lots of tiny edits to questions in bulk.

Here's an example of a user who recently edited a question of mine with pointless changes such as replacing a minus character (`-`) with a dash (`—`):

https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/2694/andhi-irawan

I assume these people do this to gain more points and to also increase exposure of their user name when questions say "*Edited by [User XXX]*" below them.

I suggest we implement a feature allowing users to report pointless edits or report users for edit spam.

Comment: Those edits do have to go through the review queue and I think we should appeal to the reviewers to reject those edits.